# how to make images directory and sub directory with webpack.

Tags: node.js, webpack

I am using Nodejs for web application development and webpack as bundler.My code is here:

Directory Structure is:

```
main.js
src
 - js
 - styles
 - images
   -logo.png
   -clients_logo
     - client_logo1.png
     - client_logo2.png
----------------------------------- 
public (Use for output)
 - js
 - css
 - images
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './main.js',
    output: { path: path.join(__dirname, './public/'), filename: './js/bundle.js' },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$/,loader:'url-loader?limit=1024&name=images/[name].[ext]' }
        ]
    }
};
```

main.js

```
import './src/images/logo.png';
require.context('./src/images/clients_logo/', true);
```

when I am compile this code using `webpack --progress --colors` command out put is:

```
public
 - images
   - logo.png
   - client_logo1.png
   - client_logo2.png
```

But Required out put is:

```
public
 - images
   - logo.png
   - clients_logo
     - client_logo1.png
     - client_logo2.png
```

I am also use

```
{ test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$/,loader:'url-loader?limit=1024&name=[path][name].[ext]?[hash]&context=/path' }
```

but it's out put is:

```
public
 - images
   - src
   - images
     - logo.png
     - clients_logo
       - client_logo1.png
       - client_logo2.png
```

So any one to understand this problem and have solution for it,Please provide it.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[path]` is the relative path of the sources, which in your case is `src/images/logo.png` and so on for the other images. With `context` the `[path]` becomes relative to that path. Setting `context=src/` will change that `[path]` to `images/logo.png`, which is exactly what you want.

So you can change your config to:

```
{
  test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$/,
  loader: 'url-loader?limit=1024&name=[path][name].[ext]&context=src/'
}
```